# How to change request url structure in activeresource ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, activeresource

Is there a configuration option avilable in ActiveResource to change the request url structure

for example when my client application try to access services of particular user from the api, ActiveResource sending request to api url in the following structure

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services.json?user_id=1
```

but instead i want the ActiveResource to send request to api url like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1/services
```

These are the two model files i am using in my client rails applicaiton

user.rb

```
 class User < ActiveResource::Base 
   self.site = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1"
   has_many :services
 end
```

service.rb

```
 class Service < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1"
   belongs_to :user 
 end
```

Any help , would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: you use the same url for the two models, shoudln't the second be different ? the correct url is defined by the receiving server, namely which route you define

Comment: @peter thanks for your reply, i don't know what you men by 'souldin't the second be different',why because `self.site` is the attribute where we use to assign the base api url, this need not to be different , i am using a single api , so the second one need not to be different.

Comment: well, how does your server know what request you make, for a User or a Service ? I think you would need at least 2 routes to serve both of them, but hey, I have no experience with ActiveResouce so I could be wrong

Comment: @peter yes the correct URL is defined by the receiving server and the receiving server URL format is this `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1/services` , when i trying to access relationship child record , the active source is sending request to api in this structure `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/services.json?user_id=1`, so that is why i want to change the active source request URL structure.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your try @peter

Comment: i see, have you seen this post about overriding the site method ? http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource?view=comments

Answer (score 0):

With these models:

```
 class User < ActiveResource::Base 
   self.site = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1"
   has_many :services
 end

 class Service < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1"
   belongs_to :user 
 end
```

ActiveResource should make the requests as follows:

```
user = User.find(1)      # GET http://localhost:3001/api/v1/users/1.json
services = user.services # GET http://localhost:3001/api/v1/users/1/services.json
```

Assuming you are going to have more options in your ActiveResource, you may consider using something like this as well:

```
 class Resource < ActiveResource::Base 
   self.site = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1"
 end

 class User < Resource 
   has_many :services
 end

 class Service < Resource
   belongs_to :user 
 end
```